# Import range from other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below you will find code to import a range from a selected file to the active workbook. The macro is assigned to a button on the active workbook.

I would like to paste the Range("U2:AH2") on the row of the active worksheet where the value of cell T2 (cell T2 is in the opened file) matches a value in column D of the table in the active worksheet.

```vb
Sub Import_QTN_Data()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Worksheets("QUOTATION").Range("U2:AH2").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QUOTATION").Range("E30").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, skipblanks:=True

    OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Match()`, or `Find()`.  Here's an example using `Match()`

```vb
Sub Import_QTN_Data()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook, wsQuote As Worksheet, m
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                  Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
                  FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set wsQuote = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QUOTATION")
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        With OpenBook.Worksheets("QUOTATION")
            'use Match() on ColD
            m = Application.Match(.Range("T2").Value, wsQuote.Columns("D"), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then       'got a match (`m` is not an error value)
                .Range("U2:AH2").Copy
                wsQuote.Cells(m, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, skipblanks:=True
            End If
        End With
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Tim it works exactly as per my needs, really appreciate your help!Many thanks for your answer